# Unparseable date error in Talend

Tags: xml, date, talend

I'm trying to input an XML document using Talend and I am getting an unparseable date error.  I've tried several different formats and can't get this to work.

Here is a line of XML it's erroring on
2012-07-03T00:00:00.000-04:00

and here's one of the formats I've tried. 
"yyyy-mm-dd'T'hh:mm:ss.SSSZ"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Marcie

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue a while back and looked up what I used - try this format in Talend: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.ss Z` and let me know if it gets rid of the error.

Answer (score 0):

if someone is in the same situation :)
i had the same problem i solved it by using "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
you can read this doc [java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)